# Need help writing a Custom Object Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I need the custom object (Installed Products) to have the same owner as the account as it will resolve some sharing issues.  The API name is SVMXC__Installed_Product__c and the Owner field name on the object is Owner.  The account linked to this object is done via a lookup as it is a managed object and has no Master.  So far I've tried to the one I used for the contact object.

On Contact:

```
trigger reassignContact on Contact (before insert, before update) {
   try {

        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id, Id> accountOwnerIdMap = new Map<Id, Id>();

        // all the accounts whose owner ids to look up
        for ( Contact c : Trigger.new ) {
            if(c.accountId <> null){
             accountIds.add( c.accountId );
            }
        }

        // look up each account owner id
        for ( Account acct : [ SELECT id, ownerId FROM account WHERE id IN :accountIds ] ) {
            accountOwnerIdMap.put( acct.id, acct.ownerId );
        }

        // change contact owner to its account owner
        for ( Contact c : Trigger.new ) {
            if(c.AccountId <> null){
             c.ownerId = accountOwnerIdMap.get( c.accountId );
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) { //catch errors
        System.Debug('reassignContacts failure: '+e.getMessage()); //write error to the debug log
    }
}
```

Here's what I've tried so far

```
trigger IPOwner on SVMXC__Installed_Product__c (before insert, before update) {
    for (SVMXC__Installed_Product__c a : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(c.AccountId <> null)
        {
            Owner.id = accountOwnerIdMap.get( c.accountId );
        }
    }
}
```

also I tried replacing `Owner.Id` with `Owner` and both give me errors.

Note my issue is not with account and contact, but trying to create similar functionality for the custom object.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please include the actual code that is generating the error and the error that you are getting. However, I think I have pieced together what you're doing. You're taking the following from the Contact trigger.

```
 // change contact owner to its account owner
for ( Contact c : Trigger.new ) {
    if(c.AccountId <> null){
     c.ownerId = accountOwnerIdMap.get( c.accountId );
    }
}
```

And trying to adapt that to your custom object. This should simply be a change to

```
 // change contact owner to its account owner
for ( SVMXC__Installed_Product__c c : Trigger.new ) {
    if(c.AccountId <> null){
     c.ownerId = accountOwnerIdMap.get( c.accountId );
    }
}
```

The Id of the owner is accessed via c.OwnerId- not c.Owner or c.Owner.Id which you say you tried. Keep in mind that you can always check the schema to see what the proper names are.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on LucidLunitic's answer, checking the API field names for standard objects are always good. [Here'](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_objects_list.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_objects_list.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)s a good place to look.
On the Contact, AccountId is a standard field but for your custom object SVMXC__Installed_Product__c you would have to have a custom relationship field.

If your going to reuse part of the Trigger, you have to instantiate and then  populate the 'accountOwnerIdMap' with the Account Id's and Owner(User) Id's you want.
Try this: (Going to assume that you have a field on SVMXC__Installed_Product__c called Account__c)

```
trigger IPOwner on SVMXC__Installed_Product__c (before insert, before update) {
  //use this to hold the account ids of the installed products
  Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
  //each of the accounts in accountIds has an owner (User) Id
  Map<Id, Id> accountOwnerIdMap = new Map<Id, Id>(); 

  // all the accounts whose owner ids to look up
  for ( SVMXC__Installed_Product__c p : Trigger.new ) {
      if (p.Account__c <> null) {
          accountIds.add( p.Account__c );
      }
  }

    // look up each account owner id
    for ( Account acct : [ SELECT id, ownerId FROM account WHERE id IN :accountIds ] ) {
        accountOwnerIdMap.put( acct.id, acct.ownerId );
    }

    // change contact owner to its account owner
   // for simplicity lets say you have a 
    for ( SVMXC__Installed_Product__c p : Trigger.new ) {
        if (p.AccountId <> null) {
            p.OwnerId = accountOwnerIdMap.get( p.Account__c );
        }
    }
}
```